# How can I get Context from a common class?

Tags: android

I know I can use getApplicationContext() to get Context from sub class of ListActivity.
but PublicPar is common class, how can I  get Context from this class.

```
public class SMSMain extends ListActivity { 

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        Context my=getApplicationContext();         
    }

}



public class PublicPar {
    public static void SetNotification(){       

    }
}
```

Comment: supply one in the constructor?

Comment: Like @panini said.  Just don't save it in a static variable.

Comment: @panini That's not a good idea. Too easy to leak the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a common (helper-type) class like your `PublicPar` class, the best you can do is to pass context as a parameter to each method:

```
public static void SetNotification(Context context) {       

}
```

Remember to not set this context to any `PublicPar` class variable to avoid leaking it.

Comment: Thanks!
Do you mean I can't do this code   public class PublicPar { public static Context myContext;  }  PublicPar.myContext =getApplicationContext();         
Why will it leak? And I think android system can avoid to  leak, right?

Comment: It can leak as you will hold a reference to the context outside of the class that inherits from it. It means you will hold the reference to the class and it won't be garbage collected. Also, having a static variable means that you have only one value so it will be easy to mix up different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work:

```
public class SMSMain extends ListActivity { 

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
       // Context my=getApplicationContext();

         new PublicPar().SetNotification(SMSMain.this)
    }

}



public class PublicPar {
    public static void SetNotification(final Context context ){       

                // You can proceed with using the context here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass the Context around as part of constructor argument, you can expose a  static method in the application.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication myinstance;
    public MyApplication() {
        myinstance = this;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        myinstance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```